# Matplotlib bar chart negative values below x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, bar-chart, axis

I'm new to using Matplotlib.
I'm trying to build a chart where values can also be negative.
Using the generic graph from matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('Python', 'C++', 'Java', 'Perl', 'Scala', 'Lisp')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [10,8,6,-4,2,1]

plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.ylabel('Usage')
plt.title('Programming language usage')

plt.show()
```

This produces

[image]

However, I would like to use x-axis as y=0 line instead of having separate y=0. So for any negative values, it would appear below x-axis and for positive values, it will appear above x-axis.

It would somehow look like this.

[image]

I've managed to get rid of the surrounding lines and values on y-axis.  Need to know how to make the x-axis the y=0 line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: In general, you should post the code showing what you've tried, not just the result.

Answer (score 7):

From [here](https://jdhao.github.io/2018/05/21/matplotlib-change-axis-intersection-point/) it's reasonably straightforward by accessing the axes object and modifying the `spines`, you just have to expose the `Axes` object first with the `plt.gca()` method.

The downside here is that getting the xticklabels how you've put them is a bit trickier, but is just a case of placing the relevant text on the `Axes` and then repeating that for the `xlabel`. You could always try using the `labelpad` argument for `plt.xlabel()` but I've not really played much with that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('Python', 'C++', 'Java', 'Perl', 'Scala', 'Lisp')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [10,8,6,-4,2,1]

plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
# Get the axes object
ax = plt.gca()
# remove the existing ticklabels
ax.set_xticklabels([])
# remove the extra tick on the negative bar
ax.set_xticks([idx for (idx, x) in enumerate(performance) if x > 0])
ax.spines["bottom"].set_position(("data", 0))
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
# placing each of the x-axis labels individually
label_offset = 0.5
for language, (x_position, y_position) in zip(objects, enumerate(performance)):
    if y_position > 0:
        label_y = -label_offset
    else:
        label_y = y_position - label_offset
    ax.text(x_position, label_y, language, ha="center", va="top")
# Placing the x-axis label, note the transformation into `Axes` co-ordinates
# previously data co-ordinates for the x ticklabels
ax.text(0.5, -0.05, "Usage", ha="center", va="top", transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: bar plot output from code above]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: is there a reason why matplotlib.pyplot is imported twice?